# How to apply Kubernetes YAML files to AWS EKS using Ansible Tower/AWX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ansible-awx, amazon-eks

From local machine, we can apply Kubernetes YAML files to [AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) using [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html) + [aws-iam-authenticator](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator) + [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/). How to do it in Ansible Tower / AWX?

Understand that there are a few Ansible modules available but none seems to be able to apply Kubernetes YAML to EKS.

- [k8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) doesn't seem to support EKS at the moment.
- [aws_eks_cluster](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_eks_cluster_module.html) only allows user to manage EKS cluster (e.g. create, remove).

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can possibly reach the goal via [k8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) module as it natively supports `kubeconfig` parameter which you can use for EKS cluster authentication. You can follow the steps described in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html) in order to compose `kubeconfig` file. There was a separate thread discussed on GitHub  [#45858](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/45858) about kubernetes manifest file implementation through k8s module, however Git contributors were facing some authorization issue, therefore take a chance and look through the conversation maybe you will find some helpful suggestions.

Comment: Have anyone figured out on how to allow kubeconfig to use the command `aws eks get-token` command? I think that's the only blocker (how to install & configure aws cli inside AWX)